# Simple way to style posts of a single category differently in the loop and in single

Tags: categories, loop, css, single

I have a certain category of posts (let's say the category is `punk-rockers`) that I would like to:

1. be styled differently from other posts in my main loop (index.php) 
   and
2. have single posts (single.php) which are styled differently from my other posts.

So, there will be four different styles, in total:

1. default loop
2. special-category loop (e.g. `punk-rockers` loop style)
3. default single post
4. special-category single post (e.g. `punk-rockers` single style)

Importantly, styles #2 and #4 are also not only different from #1 and #3, but also from each other. So not only will posts of category `punk-rockers` look different on the main loop from the other posts, but these posts will also have single-posts whose own styling will differ, depending on if it appears in the main-loop or single post.

I know I can use the existing category class `.category-punk-rockers` to modify the posts of this category in CSS, but here is my problem: **I'm not sure how about the easiest way to stylize them differently on the loop and the single.**

I would love it if you all could tell me what you think are the most elegant selectors to use/approach to take to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Note: answers to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59514/how-to-have-different-content-in-the-loop-and-single?rq=1) use php to solve some of a somewhat similar issue with content differing (as opposed to just style), but I think if I only want to change style there might be a simpler, CSS-only approach I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, since the answer seems straightforward, assuming standard templates - it's *conceivable* that your theme does not provide the kinds of classes you are asking for, but IMO would be odd.

It is standard practice for theme writers to include the function `body_class()` which adds different classes to the page's html body tag, depending on what kind of post or page you are displaying. These classes include things like:

- `archive` (for the archive page),
- `blog` (for blog or main loop),
- `home` (for home or main loop),
- `single`/`single-post` (for single),
- `category`/`category-[cat-#]` (for category).

Depending on which apply, you'll see different ones listed.

If you want to know what the classes are for your page you can view the source code, and look at the `<body>` tag at the top.

So you could use `.category-punk-rockers` to style punk-rockers. in general, `.home .category-punk-rockers` for main loop, `.archive .category-punk-rockers` for category archives, `.single-post .category-punk-rockers` for single posts, etc. Depending on what kind of widgets and extras your installation uses, you may need to create some further distinctions.

Comment: in the answer i  just wrote, I added the class `single-post` using the function `post_class()`.  Is there a function that outputs something like that already?

Comment: Exactly what you get will vary with your theme's templates and possibly with plugins, but most standard themes (starting with the WP annual themes, of course) will provide those basic ones by default. Use inspection tools to see what classes are already there for you to exploit.

Comment: Lol, that's actually what I need help with, there's too much stuff going on! I can't tell. :)

Comment: Seeing your answer above: Nothing wrong with adding your own custom classes: The more the merrier (as a general rule), as long as you don't inadvertently double up on class names in different positions. If you're adding your own custom classes with generic names, you may want to prefix or otherwise distinguish them: `codesc-single` and so on.

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to find the body classes, they're right there near the top. You'd hardly even need to search the page source.

Comment: Yes, I see the body classes now, they actually do seem to give me the control i want. I have the body classes `single` and `blog` that differ between the two. So I could use  `.blog .punk-rockers` for the index  and `.single .punk-rockers` for the single post. Thank you! I knew there must have been an easier way to do this.

Comment: My answer's perfect and beautiful! How dare you? Just kidding. Go ahead and do what you want to it, but there'll be Hell to pay if you introduce grammatical errors or other embarrassments!

Comment: Woah - excellent improvements! Now I can add the answer to my portfolio!

Comment: No problem, you clearly know your stuff. It is always nice to organize information (e.g. break it up) so others can grok it quickly.  After I write my answer, i try to clean it up so others can parse it without too much effort.  People, like me, come here because they are confused and stressed, so anything we can do it make it easier is important.

Comment: Just want to correct my solution that I listed in my above comment. I wrote: `.blog .punk-rockers` for the index and `.single .punk-rockers` for the single post.; but I should have written: `.blog .category-punk-rockers` and `.single .category-punk-rockers`.

Answer (score 0):

In "single.php" check if is category:

```
is_category( 'Punk-Rockers' );
```

and then do

```
get_template_part( 'punkrockers' );
```

With this you can do a lot of things.
Btw. this conditional tags offer a lot:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Yes, but in this case I'd have to specify the category in the php files themselves and generate php files for every category.  I want to use existing classes to do this, if possible, to save time. This way I could also apply the method to other categories easily.  I think there is likely a CSS only solution. It would involve using a parent selector that differs between index and single. something like `.index-identifying-class .category-punk-rockers` and `.single-identifying-class .category-punk-rockers`

Comment: Like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/add-category-name-body_class/?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is generalizable (meaning you can use it for other categories without needing to write specific code for each), but you do have to add a bit of code to the index.php file and the single.php file.

### In your index page

instead of just:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

you can add the class `main-index` to the post by adding a parameter to the function `post_class()`, like this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('main-index'); ?>>
```

### In your single page

instead of just:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

you can add the class `single-post` instead, using the same approach, like this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('single-post'); ?>>
```

## CSS Selectors for your stylesheet:

Then you can style the post in the index using

```
.main-index.category-punk-rockers {/*CSS*/}
```

and style the single as

```
.single-post.category-punk-rockers {*/CSS*/}
```